# No se muestran datos en campo de formulario Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

En la vista create.blade tengo un campo en el cual se deben mostrar datos para seleccionar y no se muestran, estos datos previamente han sido ingresados en otra sección en su correspondiente tabla de base de datos.

Los demás campos muestran los datos correctamente pero en Excedente no logro que aparezcan. Ademas el campo Excedente esta conectado con Stock ya que son de la misma tabla de base de datos, es decir cuando se selecciona un excedente se debe cargar el stock de éste automáticamente, obviamente que esto no lo he podido comprobar por el problema anteriormente descrito.

Aquí dejo una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Aqui dejo el function create del controller:

```
public function create()
    {

        $excedentes = DB::table('excedentes as ex')
            ->join('detallerea as drea','ex.idexcedente','=','drea.idexcedente')
            ->join('prestador_seguro as pre','drea.idprestador','=','pre.idprestador')
            ->select('ex.idexcedente','ex.nombre','ex.stock','pre.nombre')
            ->where('ex.condicion','=','1')
            ->where('ex.stock','>','0')
            ->get();

        $pacientesm = DB::table('pmedicamentos')->get();

        $prestador = DB::table('prestador_seguro')->get();

        $tiposolicitud = DB::table('tipo_solicitud')->get();

        return view("reasignaciones.create", [
            "excedentes"=>$excedentes,
            "pacientesm"=>$pacientesm,
            "prestador"=>$prestador,
            "tiposolicitud"=>$tiposolicitud

        ]);
    }
```

Y aqui el campo correspondiente a excedente en la vista create.blade:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Excedente</label>
                            <select name="pidexcedente" class="form-control selectpicker" id="pidexcedente" data-live-search="true">
                                @foreach($excedentes as $exc)
                                <option value="{{$exc->idexcedente}}_{{$exc->stock}}">{{$exc->Nombre}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Aguardo sus respuestas y si es necesario que suba algo mas del código, favor de decirme, gracias.

Comment: ¿No sería más fácil usar eloquent para hacer esa consulta que obtiene excedentes? es muchísimo más fácil según mi experiencia.

Comment: ¿Como debería proceder? es que soy nuevo en esto y me vengo guiando por videotutoriales

Comment: Lo ideal sería que te guiaras por la documentación, los videotutoriales no necesariamente son de buena calidad (de hecho la gran mayoría son de baja calidad), salvo que sean los de Styde o los de Laracasts.

Comment: Revisa tu sql por si no se estuviera haciendo como tú esperas escribiendo la consulta en el log con el método `toSql()` (se pone en lugar del `get()`): `DB::table("excedentes as ex")->...->toSql();`